# xslt group by function or append to array

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have collection of items:

```
<items>
    <result>
        <item>
            <product_name>some description</product_name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <product_name>some similar description</product_name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <product_name>other product size 1</product_name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <product_name>other product size 2</product_name>
        </item>
    </result>
</items>
```

I also have some external function `strdist:string-distance` that compares previous product to current one and if there is some match then it returns true. Based on this returned value I'd like to:

- add the current element of `for-each` to the group of previous element when returned value is `true`
- close previous group, create a new group and add current element of `for-each` loop to it when returned value is `false`

I'm little bit struggling with the process of how to create the groups and add there elements in `for-loop`.

Here is my template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:strdist="http://example.com/string-distance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="strdist">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="items" as="element()*">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="items/result/item">
                <xsl:sort select="./product_name"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="groupedItems" as="element()*">
            <groups>
                <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="currentProductName" select="./product_name/text()"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$position -1 = 0">
                            <xsl:element name="group"/>
                            <xsl:message select="concat($position, ' # ', $currentProductName)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$position -1 > 0">
                            <xsl:variable name="previousProductName"
                                          select="$items[position() = $position -1]/product_name/text()"/>
                            <xsl:message
                                    select="concat($position, ' # ', $previousProductName, ' # ', $currentProductName)"/>
                            <xsl:message select="strdist:string-distance($previousProductName, $currentProductName)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </groups>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message select="$groupedItems" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally I'd like to have something like this:

```
<items>
    <result>
        <group>
            <item>
                <product_name>some description</product_name>
            </item>
            <item>
                <product_name>some similar description</product_name>
            </item>
        </group>
        <group>
            <item>
                <product_name>other product size 1</product_name>
            </item>
            <item>
                <product_name>other product size 2</product_name>
            </item>
        </group>
    </result>
</items>
```

I'm using `xslt 2.0` with `saxon-he 10.3`.

Comment: It sounds like a job for `xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-adjacent="product_name"` or perhaps a use of a custom function in `group-adjacent="pf:fun1(product_name)"`. `for-each` won't help, in XSLT 3 (which Saxon HE 10 certainly supports), if you really can't get it to work with `for-each-group`, your algorithm might be adaptable to `xsl:iterate`. Or `fold-left` in a more functional manner.

Comment: or maybe to just create a copy of current `item` + adding some new field `groupId` (it changes based on result from custom function)  and then in next iteration group by this groupId...but don't know if that will be efficient.

Comment: @MartinHonnen so looks like it works with `for-each-group` and `group-adjacent`. Just is there some trick how to fix last element? `group-adjacent="strdist:string-distance(self::item/product_name/text(), following-sibling::*[1]/product_name/text())"` because it fails on last one when there is no next element obviously. I also control that function needs both parameters filled.

Comment: Inside of the `group-adjacent` you should be able to check e.g. `if (position() = last()) then .. else ..` to adapt the value, I am not quite sure I have understood the criteria how to treat the last element to spell out something more concrete. Perhaps another option is using `for-each-group select="item" group-starting-with="item[not(strdist:string-distance(product_name, preceding-sibling::item[1]/product_name))]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example using `for-each-group group-starting-with` and a sample function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:string-distance" as="xs:boolean">
      <xsl:param name="name1" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:param name="name2" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="tokenize($name1)[1] = tokenize($name2)[1]"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="result">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-starting-with="item[not(mf:string-distance(product_name, preceding-sibling::item[1]/product_name))]">
              <group>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </group>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Seems to give the wanted result at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrR.

Comment: It's even easier than I thought...just need read more about `for-each-group`. Thank you!